# Navigate pages of ag grid using keyboard

Tags: accessibility, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am unable to navigate to the footer of the ag grid using tab buttons which contains next and previous page button. I have to always use the mouse to focus the table footer and then I am able to use the tab keys to navigate across the page.

Is there a way to navigate to the table footer directly from last cell of the last row.

Comment: Is there an example URL to test?  I tried https://www.ag-grid.com/example but it does not have a table footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to the last cell in the  last row using the combination `Cmd+Down+Right`. After that you can `Tab` to pagination buttons or `Shift+Tab` to  go back

Comment: I seem to have a strange issue. I have two ag grids in my applcaition. the one which has buttons in the last column is not able to move focus to pagintation on tab press. The other table which has just plain text in the last column is working fine with just "TAB" press i am able to navigate to paginatin buttons

Comment: In your first grid, where you have buttons in the last column, you probably have a bug in a cell renderer. This cell rendered, I assume, suppress keyboard events to manage tabbing within buttons inside the cell. Do you have `suppressKeyboardEvent` callback on that column?

Comment: Yes, I did write the supresskeyboardevent to supress the tab key to focus the button. But i require that as well otherwise user cannot click on the button inside the last cell via keyboard to perform an action